# Why can't I run a blank Cordova app in browser: You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, cordova, browser

I'm following the Get Started tutorial on https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted but I'm getting an error despite following the instructions clearly, this is what I did:

```
npm install -g cordova
cordova create myApp
cd myApp
cordova platform add browser
cordova run browser
```

but at the end of the last command, I get an error:

```
C:\code\cordova\test
λ cordova run browser
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\code\cordova\test\platforms\browser\cordova\run.bat""
C:\code\cordova\test\platforms\browser\cordova\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\q\q.js:155
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1139:19)
    at listen (net.js:1182:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
    at module.exports (C:\code\cordova\test\platforms\browser\cordova\node_modules\cordova-serve\src\server.js:134:8)
    at C:\code\cordova\test\platforms\browser\cordova\node_modules\cordova-serve\src\platform.js:45:16
    at _fulfilled (C:\code\cordova\test\platforms\browser\cordova\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\code\cordova\test\platforms\browser\cordova\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\code\cordova\test\platforms\browser\cordova\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\code\cordova\test\platforms\browser\cordova\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\q\q.js:857:14
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I'm using NodeJS v0.12.7 and Cordova 5.4.0

Comment: try updating to node 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the tutorial you linked says browser for some reason. I don't see it on their "supported platform list", try using a platform which you think you're going to develop for and see if you have the same issues.

Link to the platform list (odd that browser isn't listed): https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/support/index.html

Comment: Worked with android, thanks. I guess it's an issue on their guides

Comment: If the official docs could mention the browser platform, that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

I have had a similar issue on my **Debian 8.3 (jessie)** with an installed **Chromium** from the offical debian package-sources.

The detailled error message was:

`Error: Error executing "google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/temp_chrome_user_data_dir_for_cordova http://localhost:8000/index.html": /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found`

To fix the issue, I have downloaded the (Google-) **Chrome**-Browser [directly from their website](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/), and installed the .deb-package.

After that I did a

```bash
cordova platform rm browser
cordova platform add browser
cordova build browser
cordova run browser
```

and it finally worked.

**Summary:**

Chromium doesn't work - use chrome

Answer (score 1):

This is a late reply, maybe will help someone else.

instead of
cordova run browser

You should try "cordova serve" command after the add platform browser..

> cordova platform add browser
>
> cordova serve

after this hopefully if everything is set up right , you will get a message
"server runing on localhost:/port" . Just goto that address on your browser..

see the magic.

Comment: This opens up a static file server on that address and port and if the browser platform is not correctly installed, then the browser directory will not be clickable. But apparently, the android one is clickable and it does open up the html file in the local server...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Cordova Windows Platform Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html)

It goes more into detail about running Cordova on a windows platform.

### Requirements:

#### To develop apps for Windows platform:

Windows 8.0, 8.1, or 10, 32 or 64 bit Home, Pro, or Enterprise

Visual Studio 2013

#### To develop apps for Windows 10:

Visual Studio 2015 RC or higher

*Note: For Windows 10, the Visual Studio installer has an option to install tools to build Universal Windows Apps. You must ensure that this option is selected when installing to install the required SDK.*

### Create a New Project

At this point, to create a new project you can choose between the cross-platform CLI tool described in The Command-Line Interface, or the set of Windows-specific shell tools. The CLI approach below generates an app named HelloWorld within a new hello project directory:

```
> cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
> cd hello
> cordova platform add windows
```

Here's the corresponding lower-level shell-tool approach:

```
C:\path\to\cordova-windows\package\bin\create.bat C:\path\to\new\hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

### Build the Project

If you are using the CLI in development, the project directory's top-level www directory contains the source files. Run either of these within the project directory to rebuild the app:

```
> cordova build
> cordova build windows              # do not rebuild other platforms
> cordova build windows   --debug    # generates debugging information
> cordova build windows   --release  # signs the apps for release
```

Here's the corresponding lower-level shell-tool approach:

```
C:\path\to\project\cordova\build.bat --debug        
C:\path\to\project\cordova\build.bat --release
```

The clean command helps flush out directories in preparation for the next build:

```
C:\path\to\project\cordova\clean.bat
```

### Deploy the app

To deploy Windows package:

```
> cordova run windows -- --win  # explicitly specify Windows as deployment target
> cordova run windows # `run` uses Windows package by default
```

Also before executing the command:

```
cordova create myApp
```

make sure to cd into a user directory or a directory where you will keep your cordova apps

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, whenever you link an external reference, add a summary to it. The link may become invalid in the future and we would lose your answer in that case! Thank you!

Comment: The question clearly states it is about the browser platform, not windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why you want to deploy it from the command line to a browser instead of a device or an emulator.

Wouldn't you just open index.html in the browswer?

Comment: I think he was just trying to "get started", as opposed to specifying a platform to be a phone platform or other. check out the link he posted, his attempts are verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I also had this problem, and couldn't figure out what was going on for the life of me. I finally figured it out:

The guy didn't have Chrome installed. Installed Chrome, poof, problem solved.

Let this be a lesson for us all.

Comment: I had chrome installed but the problem still persisted...odd.